# Use Python function to find the element with the maximum length

Tags: python

I'm new to python and having some difficulty troubleshooting my script.

I want to use functions to:

first function: to find the length of each element in the list "names"

second function: use a score function to each string in the names list and returns the name with the highest score (in this particular case, the score is the length of the element calculated by the first function) If there are ties in the list, return the first item with the maximum score.

```
def length(names):
    for i in names:
        word_len = [len(i)]
    return word_len

def best(score, names):
    x = map (score, names)
    return x

names = ["John", "Megan", "Wenister", "J.M"]


print(best(length, names), "has the longest name.")
```

Comment: You can use `max()` with `key=len`.

Comment: Is it crashing? What's not working / what result are you getting?

Comment: `max(names, key=len)` gives `'Wenister'`

Answer (score 0):

```
def longest(names_list):

    if len(names_list) == 0:
        return None
    return max(names_list, key=lambda name: len(name))

names = ["John", "Megan", "Wenister", "J.M"]

print(longest(names))
```

Comment: I can see what you're saying, but we're experienced programmers.  This user is a new programmer.  While looking up `max` is easy, understanding `lamba` is not and understanding `key=lambda name: len(name)` is not straightforward in an sense.  Sometimes an explanation means, including a link to the appropriate resource.

Answer (score -1):

Use the max function to get the maximum length of the string.

```
names = ["John", "Megan", "Wenister", "J.M"]
print(len(max(names)), max(names), "has the longest name.")
```

Here I wrote without your function, you can use this.

## OUTPUT:

8 Wenister has the longest name.

Comment: That is not a solution for the problem asked here, because you misunderstand the default calculation of the maximum of strings by `max()`. Try e.g. `names = ["John", "Zoe", "Wenister", "J.M"]`...